# Can I apply an hilbert transform on a signal in subsegments [windowed hilbert transform?]

Tags: python, hilbert-transform, window, analytic-signal, segmentation

Consider I have a signal x which has N samples, N being a very large number.

Could I create `y`, the analytical signal of `x`, by taking `y[i:i+8] = H(x[i:i+8])` while looping over `i` in increments of 8?

Like, moving a window over the signal and taking the hilbert transform of it by moving the window in steps of 8 each time.

In Python that would look like:

```
for n in range(int(N/8)):
    i = n * 8
    y[i:i+8] = scipy.signal.hilbert(x[i:i+8])
```

The reason for me wanting to do this is because I'm implementing the Hilbert transform on an FPGA which takes in only 8 samples at the time in the current VHDL code.

When I compare the signal with `scipy.signal.hilbert(x)`, in which I do not take segments but just analyze the whole signal, the outcome is different.

Could someone explain to me why that is and second, what a method could be for me to approach my problem?

Thanks!

Full Python code for testing:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal


N = 32          
x = np.random.rand(N) * 10

y = [0] * N
for n in range(int(N/8)):
    i = n * 8
    y[i:i+8] = scipy.signal.hilbert(x[i:i+8])

z = scipy.signal.hilbert(x)

for i in range(N):
    print(f"{i} => segmented: {y[i]}")
    print(f"{i} => full: {z[i]}\n")
```

It can be noted that the real part of the analytical, segmented signal is fine, but the imaginary component is different compared to the analytical full signal.

I did take a look at: [Hilbert transform with a sliding window](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/44989/hilbert-transform-with-a-sliding-window) but I cannot figure out if this does the same for which I'm confused about.

Comment: What's your application? What frequency range needs to be accurate? What is the overall accuracy goal? What are your latency constraints?

Answer (score 1):

> Could I create `y`, the analytical signal of `x`, by taking `y[i:i+8] = H(x[i:i+8])` while looping over `i` in increments of 8?

No. It doesn't work this way since the Hilbert Transform of an 8-sample finite sequence is not 8 samples long: it's infinitely long and so the results of the individual sections will overlap (a lot).

> what a method could be for me to approach my problem?

Your best shot here is to implement the HT as an FIR filter. The length of that filter depends on how good the HT needs to be and the specific requirements of your application.

Comment: I’m fully prepared to build it myself but would you mind providing some directions or links to examples? And/or maybe describe why that could work

Comment: Do you know what an FIR filter is and how to implement it ?